# Make text field empty by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textfield

On my site, I'd like to implement a filter that allows users to filter an event based on their range. For example: there are many videos in the database (short videos or short films or feature films). I would like that the user in the field could type, for example, in the "from" field - the number 60, and in the "to" field - the number 120, and he was given films lasting from 60 to 120 minutes.

I already have certain developments. I implemented the input field using TextField. I also made restrictions on the number of characters entered (the number entered cannot be more than seven characters).

But I have a problem that by default in these fields is zero (and also zero appears after the user deletes the previously entered value). Please tell me how can I make the field empty by default.

```
    const MAX_DURATION = 9999999

export default function Duration() {
  const { filters, setFilters } = useContext(PageContext);
  const [minDuration, setMinDuration] = useState(filters.durationRange.start);
  const [maxDuration, setMaxDuration] = useState(filters.durationRange.end);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMinDuration(filters.durationRange.start);
    setMaxDuration(filters.durationRange.end);
  },
    [filters.durationRange.start, filters.durationRange.end]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var updatedFilters = { ...filters }
    updatedFilters.durationRange = { start: minDuration, end: maxDuration }
    setFilters(updatedFilters)
  }, [minDuration, maxDuration]);


  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            label="From"
            value={minDuration}
            onInput={(e) => {
              e.target.value = Math.max(e.target.value).toString().slice(0, 7)
              const newValue = Number(e.target.value)
              if (newValue) {
                setMinDuration(newValue)
              } else if (newValue == 0) {
                setMinDuration(0)
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <TextField
            label="To"
            value={maxDuration}
            onInput={(e) => {
              e.target.value = Math.max(e.target.value).toString().slice(0, 7)
              const newValue = Number(e.target.value)
              if (newValue) {
                setMaxDuration(newValue)
              } else if (newValue === 0) {
                setMaxDuration(0)
              }
              else setMaxDuration(MAX_DURATION)
            }}
          />
        </div>

      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because any time you delete the text from the input, the empty string is going to be type coerced to the value `0`.

To solve this, you could create a function that returns the empty string if the value is equal to `''`.

```
function getInputValue(value) {
  if (value === '') { // make sure it is ===, not ==
    return '';
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Just call the function on the textfield:

```
<TextField label="From" value={getInputValue(minDuration)} ... />
```

Comment: Probably in your code you meant
if (value === 0) . I think it should work, I will check and get back to you

Comment: It has to be `''`, because you still want to be able to type `0` into the input

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem that by default in these fields is zero (and also
> zero appears after the user deletes the previously entered value).
> Please tell me how can I make the field empty by default.

The returned value from `Number('')` is `0`

In your `onInput` handler you have:

```js
} else if ( newValue === 0 ) {
    setMaxDuration( 0 );
}
```

The problem is that you're setting the input's value back to `0`. This is the same for the other input too.

Listening for the `input` event might not be what you want, perhaps consider listening for the `change` event

Comment: Yes, I understand that with this code I set the value to zero. But how can I make the field empty if the value is set to zero.